# I'm surrounded by idiots. Who do I have to kill to get my hands on a superior brain?

Tags: starbound

> **Note:** This question refers to content only available in beta. **As of stable 1.0 version of the game, this item is no longer available**

I'm trying to build the Inactive Robot, which requires me to build a Robot Head. Only, to build the Robot Head, it turns out I need to get my hands on a Superior Brain. I've been running around Sector B killing monsters and ape-men alike, but when I use the Brain Extractor on them, I just keep getting Inferior Brains.

Where can I find a Superior Brain?

Comment: An excellent question title, +1

Comment: I thought you were asking a question about dota when I read your title :D

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Every monster has a 7% chance of dropping a Superiour Brain instead of an Inferior Brain when killed with a Brain Extractor. Just keep killing monsters, and you will get one.

Answer (score 6):

From my own experience it's just a rarer drop than the inferior brains. They can drop from any monsters killed by the brain extractor.